# Declare a global object inside of a function (c++)

Tags: c++, global-variables

I'm declaring objects of a struct inside of a function and i'd like to access said objects outside of that function (making them global). Here's an example of what i'd like to do

```
            #include <iostream>
            using namespace std;

            struct exampleStruct
            {
                int ID;
            };

            void makeExampleStruct ()
            {
                exampleStruct exampleObj[30];

                for (int r=0;r<=30;r++)
                {
                    exampleObj[r].ID=r;
                }
            }

            int main()
            {
                makeExampleStruct();
                cout << exampleObj[1].ID << endl;
                return 0;
            }
```

This gives me a "'exampleObj' was not declared in this scope". I know i could simply declare the objects creation inside of main, but i'd rather keep it inside of a function so it's easier to read. Is there a way of doing that?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to declare the variable globally (outside of the function)
use the function to change the global variable.

Variables declared inside of a function are only accessible in that function; they are called [local variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_variable) as they are local to the function in which they are declared.

The `main()` function cannot access the local variables of another function.

Globally declared variables are visible everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

After the function is called, your array no longer exists:

```
void makeExampleStruct ()
{
    exampleStruct exampleObj[30];
      // exampleObj is created here

    for (int r=0;r<=30;r++)
    {
        exampleObj[r].ID=r;
    }

    // exampleObj is destroyed here.
}
```

So even if you could access the object, it would be illegal to do so after the function returns, since the object's lifetime has ended.

Answer (score 0):

No. You need to declare it outside the function otherwise it is local.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot provide global access to local variables from functions. What you can do instead is something like making them `static` and return a reference:

```
exampleStruct[30]& makeExampleStruct () {
     static exampleStruct exampleObj[30];
     static bool isinitialized = false;

     if(!isinitialized) {
          for (int r=0;r<=30;r++) {
               exampleObj[r].ID=r;
          }
          isinitialized = true;
     }

    return exampleObj;
}
```